# eclipse doesn't build referenced project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been using [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) for a while in my app, but after I had to format my pc, I had often errors building APK's. So I changed some Build Path settings until it worked to build an apk. Unfortunately the app crashed (ClassNotFoundError for a class in ViewPagerIndicator), when I used the ViewPagerIndicator in an activity, but it was still in the buildpath as referenced project. I've tried every combination (unchecking IsLibrary, Deleting and Re-referencing, even create a new Project with the source files)

Do you know where my error is?

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup, yours should be similar.

> viewpagerindicator
>
> -isLibrary = true
>
> myproject
>
> -isLibrary = (well depends if your project is a library or not)
>
> In the same section hit 'add' to add viewpagerindicator as a library
> project (this sets your build path, you don't need to change it
> manually)

Now look at your build path, it should only contain your /src and /gen folders (nothing from VPI)  Look at the 'Libraries' tab, you should see a VPI.jar under Library Projects.

Notes: viewpagerindicator must compile for this to work, so make sure that is happening.

Also make sure you have the latest version of the tools (ADTr16), previously r14 had some issues when they introduced the new way libraries are compiled. http://tools.android.com/recent